# Creating formula object for coxph()

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am trying to create the formula object for `coxph()` manually, as I want to reproduce it in [RSRuby](http://rubygems.org/gems/rsruby). Note that the response variable needs to be a `Surv` object, the output of the `Surv()` method. The `Surv` object is basically a matrix with columns `time` and `status`.

Now, I am doing the following:

```
length_of_stay <- c(13, 4, 5, 21, 33, 10) 
exited_care <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1) 
survival_object <- Surv(length_of_stay, exited_care)
gender <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
mydata <- data.frame(length_of_stay = length_of_stay, 
                     exited_care = exited_care, 
                     gender = gender)
data_frame_for_formula <- data.frame(cbind(survival_object, gender))
my_formula <- formula(data_frame_for_formula)
mod.los <- coxph(formula = my_formula, data = mydata)
```

and getting the following error message:

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'status' not found"
```

`traceback()` shows the formula is

```
time ~ status + gender
```

How can I avoid that and make the survival object the response variable?

Comment: If there is no interest in the statistical aspect of fitting survival data, this question should probably be posted to Stack Overflow. We can migrate this question for you if this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue arise from how `formula.data.frame` (the method associated with data.frames) works and how `data.frame(cbind(...))` strips the `Surv` object of the `Surv` class attribute.

What you want is

```
 mod.los <- coxph(Surv(length_of_stay, exited_care)~ gender, data = mydata)
```

Or perhaps

```
  mod.los <- coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ gender, data = data_frame_for_formula)
```